# Joining tables that don't have a common id

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables in a MySQL database.  One is "accounts" and one is "posts".  I'm at the point where I want to allow users to only edit their posts, which I think means I need to create a table join.  The problem is there isn't a common id for each table.

**Accounts**:
id, first_name, last_name, username, password, email, activation_code, rememberme, role

**Posts**:
id, title, body, author, tags, status, image, created_at

I'm still searching on how to do this.  I know I need to create a common id. That's where I'm getting confused since there will need to be a common link when a post is created.  Can someone point me in the right direction for making this happen please?

Comment: The `author` value in `Posts` should be a foreign key to `Accounts`, ideally it should point to the `id` value.

Comment: FKs & other constraints are not needed to query. Any 2 tables can be joined on any condition whose columns are known. Give a [mre] for your problem & explain how you are stuck. Now it is not clear what your problem is. But we can expect this to be a faq.. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Thanks @Nick - that's a good indicator and I learned something new.  I'm going to see where I can take it from here.  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @SteveShead no worries - good luck.

Comment: Seems I'm missing something.  I'm getting the error `#1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint` - the ID field is INT and the author is VARCHAR - still researching.

Comment: @Nick - once I worked out that the foreign key needed to be INT I got it sorted by creating a new column in `posts` called `user_id`, mapped the user_id to the account table `$user_id = $_SESSION['id'], then added user_id to the insert query.  That worked - I'm hoping I didn't break any rules doing that - I'm using PDO by the way.  Again, thanks for the assist.

Comment: @SteveShead that sounds like the right way to go, although is there any duplication between the `author` and `user_id` fields?

Comment: @Nick - no, at least I don't think so since author is a text field and user_id is an INT.  Anyone can write anything into the text field - if that makes sense?

Comment: @SteveShead yeah. I wasn't sure if `author` was actually the name associated with the `user_id` value, in which case you would have redundant and possibly incorrect information between the two tables.

Comment: @Nick - I appreciate you checking - thanks for the assist.  As soon as I managed to add the foreign key creating the pdo query felt intuitive!  Again, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The "author" column in Posts table should ideally be a foreign key of the "id" column in Accounts table. This would allow you to join the tables based on this column. A foreign key can be added as follows for your case -

```
ALTER TABLE Posts ADD FOREIGN KEY (author) REFERENCES Accounts(id);
```

You can have a look at a tutorial about foreign keys here - https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp

Comment: Thanks - I get the concept - though when I try I get an error "cannot add foreign key".  I've checked that the collation is the same - seems I'm missing something.

Comment: As per one of your comments, it seems that you are storing different types of data in the two columns? The author contains the name of the author whereas the id is a unique ID for the author. I would suggest you use the ID for both of the tables. And when you want to display the name of the user, you check in the Users table to whom the ID corresponds to.

Comment: Ah - that makes sense.  Thanks for the reply.

Comment: I believe I have this sorted now.  I created the foreign key called user_id in the posts table and set that to the ID column in the accounts table. Since in the login process I have the ID as a session variable, I added `$user_id = $_SESSION['id'];` then added user_id to the insert statement `INSERT INTO posts(title, body, author, tags, status, image, user_id) VALUES (:title, :body, :author, :tags, :status, :image, :user_id)` - which worked.  Thanks for the assist - very helpful.

Comment: That's great, no problem!